# Query Azure Cosmos DB collection based on item status

Tags: sql, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In Azure Cosmos DB on Azure I have a collection with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "status": "wait",
    "order": {
            "orderId": "P1000",
            "orderPositionId": "1"
    }   
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "status": "wait",
    "order":{
            "orderId": "P1000",
            "orderPositionId": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "status": "start",
    "order":{
            "orderId": "P1000",
            "orderPositionId": "1"
    }
  }
]
```

The combination of orderId and orderPositionId are unique.

I want to query all items with status "wait" for which no item with the status "start" exists.

For above example the desired result of the query is:

```
[
{
    "id": "2",
    "status": "wait",
    "order":{
            "orderId": "P1000",
            "orderPositionId": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

My idea is doing this(**Pseudocode**)

```
SELECT *FROM c
WHERE 
c.status="wait"
AND
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM c 
       WHERE c.order.orderId = c.order.orderId **(id of current item)** AND 
             c.order.orderPositionId=c.order.orderPositionId **(id of current item)** AND 
             c.status="start") = false
```

I know that this idea will not work this way.
I am new to Cosmos DB and also to SQL API and I am not able to figure out a working solution. I am thankful for any hints on how to solve this.

Thanks, let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: If you add `c.status  = 'wait'`, the `start` items are not included,are they? Or i misunderstand something here?

Comment: Hey @JayGong, you are right that the `start` items are not included and I am able to get all the `wait` items. But my goal is to drop all `wait` items which have a corresponding `start` item.

Comment: Hey @JayGong. Just found the time to verify your answer. Thank you so much! Your answer really helped me and the queries give the results I was looking for. I now have to find a way to implement the consecutive queries. But I assume that this can be implemented using stored procedures.

Comment: You're so kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But my goal is to drop all wait items which have a corresponding start
>   item.

So,according to this,if there are 2 documents:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "status": "wait",
    "order": {
            "orderId": "P1000",
            "orderPositionId": "1"
    }   
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "status": "start",
    "order":{
            "orderId": "P1000",
            "orderPositionId": "1"
    }
  }
```

They have same:

```
 "order":{
            "orderId": "P1000",
            "orderPositionId": "1"
 }
```

Then you need to remove such `wait` one from `wait` family.

Based on my lots of test,i can't use sub query with array_contains method.So i have to use 2 sql to implement your requirement.

First sql to query all the `start` items:

```
SELECT c['order'].orderId,c['order'].orderPositionId FROM c
where c.status = 'start'
```

And you will get array result:

[image]

Then use that array in below long sql:

```
select c.id,c.status,c['order'] 
from c
where c.status = 'wait' and not EXISTS 
(select value c from c 
where c.status = 'wait' and arraycontains(
[
    {
        "orderId": "P1000",
        "orderPositionId": "1"
    }
],{"orderId": c['order'].orderId,"orderPositionId":c['order'].orderPositionId},true))
```

You could get output:

[image]